# кеширование результатов геокодирования яндекс

Tags: yandex-maps-api, кэширование

Используем на сайте геокодер яндекса для доставки. Недавно было уменьшено количество запросов до 1000.... Буквально за 4-5 часов уходят все запросы, хотя заказов может быть 10... Скорее всего запросы тратятся на бэкенде нами же. Прочитал, что можно кешировать повторные результаты геокодирования и возможно это то, что нам нужно. Перелазил весь гугл и не нашел никакой информации про то, как настроить кеширование результатов геокодера... Может тут мне смогут подсказать, как реализовать данный функционал. За ранее спасибо!!

Comment: Самое простое - храните в базе данных, через 30 дней удалять. В качестве ключа можно использовать параметр geocode.
И написать какую-то функцию, которая по строке запроса будет сначала искать ответ геокодера в локальной базе, а потом уже отправлять запрос в Яндекс, если не найдет локально.